# Jenkins Ivy Plugin - seperate Jobs and Success/Fail message

Tags: jenkins, ivy

We use the Jenkins Ivy Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ivy+Plugin).

When we have inserted some root folder with several individual projects and activated the option "Build modules as separate jobs" everything works as desired.

The only thing is: Is there a way to let this job say it is finished when it actually build all sub-jobs successfully? Currently it triggers the sub-jobs and says it's successful.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be an ivy issue. Frankly, I don't understand the question.

Comment: The issue is for example if I have an Ivy Job configured which checks out some svn folder that includes 5 Java Projects and tell the Plugin that it should build the Projects as individual projects. What it does is to trigger the execution -> Job Finish - State "Success". What I would expect is that is triggers the execution and if some project fails it displays "Job failed" if ALL projects succeed it displays "Success"

Comment: Again this does not appear to be an ivy issue, rather a Jenkins issue (Perhaps a Jenkins plugin issue, don't know I always call ivy from within ANT). Normally a Jenkins job works against a single workspace, you appear to want Jenkins to run 5 builds from the same workspace? The only suggestion I have is create an ANT build.xml file in the root of the svn checkout that runs the 5 project builds. That way there is a single controlling process.

Comment: In the meantime I did it that way. Thank you for your response!